# Inserting rows in a table to mimic other rows only when they don't exist

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table (named **UserAccess**) designed like this...

```
[ID], [UserID], [Active]
```

I have a table (named **UserAccounts**) designed like this...

```
[UserID], [Password], [Group]
```

In the **UserAccess** table I currently have the following data...

```
1203, 'user1', 1
1203, 'user2', 1
1203, 'user4', 1
1202, 'user1', 1
1203, 'user8', 1
1202, 'user6', 1
1206, 'user2', 1
1205, 'user2', 1
1204, 'user1', 1
1204, 'user6', 1
```

In the **UserAccounts** table I currently have the following data...

```
'user1', 'password', 'group1'
'user2', 'password', 'group10'
'user3', 'password', 'group1'
'user4', 'password', 'group4'
'user5', 'password', 'group10'
'user6', 'password', 'group10'
'user7', 'password', 'group2'
'user8', 'password', 'group10'
```

I want to add new rows for users that belong to 'group10' so that they mimic each row for 'user2' that do not already exist into the **UserAccess** table.  As an example the results should be...

```
  1203, 'user1', 1
  1203, 'user2', 1
  1203, 'user4', 1
  1202, 'user1', 1
  1203, 'user8', 1
  1202, 'user6', 1
  1206, 'user2', 1
  1205, 'user2', 1
  1204, 'user1', 1
  1205, 'user6', 1
* 1203, 'user5', 1
* 1206, 'user5', 1
* 1205, 'user5', 1
* 1203, 'user6', 1
* 1206, 'user6', 1
* 1206, 'user8', 1
* 1205, 'user8', 1
```

The new results show the added rows are the rows with an asterisk in front of them.  What's the best way to accomplish this?  I was trying to use something like this but just can't seem to get the result that I'm after, Honestly I just can't seem to get close to what I want...

Note: `@UserId` should change going through each user.

```
DECLARE @ModelId varchar(30); SET @ModelId = 'user2';
INSERT INTO UserAccess ([ID], [UserID])
SELECT [ID], @UserId, FROM UserAccess
WHERE [UserID] = @ModelId
```

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to add, I tried to use some `INNER JOIN` statements too with no luck...  :/

Comment: How is the `ID` field in `UserAccess` generated?

Comment: From a different table.  In the other table called `Task` it gets auto generated and a few more fields are set in there manually.  But I would like to stay away from "that" table if possible.

Comment: Will all added records will have a value of `Active` equalling `1`?  If a record to be inserted already exists in `UserAccess` but with another value for `Active` should we change the existing records value of `Active` to `1`?

Comment: Yes they will, all added rows need to be `Active` by default.  There should NEVER be two rows with the same ID and UserID regardless of the value of the `Active` column.

Comment: Does the existing value have dominance?

Comment: Yes if a row already exists then one CANNOT be inserted.  That's why I was using `NOT EXISTS` on my test queries too.  (I just noticed I never added them to the end of my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
INSERT INTO UserAccess
SELECT ID,
       UserID,
       1
FROM UserAccounts outerUserAccounts,
     ( SELECT ID
       FROM UserAccess
       WHERE UserID = 'user2' ) AS selectedIDs
WHERE [Group] = 'Group10'
  AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                   FROM UserAccess
                   WHERE UserAccess.ID = selectedIDs.ID
                     AND UserAccess.UserID = outerUserAccounts.UserID );
```

I started by first identifying which values of `ID` were associated with the specified `UserID` (in this case `user2`) using the following SQL statement...

```
SELECT ID
FROM UserAccess
WHERE UserID = 'user2'
```

I then perfromed a `CROSS JOIN` on the generated table (which I called `selectedIDs`) and those records from `UserAccounts` where the Users belonged to the specified `Group` (in this case `Group10`).  (Please note that `UserAccounts, selectedIDs` is the same as `UserAccounts CROSS JOIN selectedIDs`.)

The resulting table contains the values of `ID` and `UserID` that will need to be inserted into `UserAccounts`, but it may also contain records that already exist in `UserAccounts`.  Therefore the following `WHERE` clause was added to the `SELECT` statement...

```
NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
             FROM UserAccess
             WHERE UserAccess.ID = selectedIDs.ID
             AND UserAccess.UserID = outerUserAccounts.UserID )
```

This clause tests to see if the values being considered by the main statement do not already exist in `UserAccess`.

My code was tested against a sample database created using the following script...

```
CREATE TABLE UserAccess
(
    ID       INT,
    UserID   VARCHAR( 10 ),
    Active   INT
);
CREATE TABLE UserAccounts
(
    UserID    VARCHAR( 10 ),
    [Password]   VARCHAR( 10 ),
    [Group]      VARCHAR( 10 )
);
INSERT INTO UserAccess ( ID,
                         UserID,
                         Active )
VALUES ( 1203, 'user1', 1 ),
       ( 1203, 'user2', 1 ),
       ( 1203, 'user4', 1 ),
       ( 1202, 'user1', 1 ),
       ( 1203, 'user8', 1 ),
       ( 1202, 'user6', 1 ),
       ( 1206, 'user2', 1 ),
       ( 1205, 'user2', 1 ),
       ( 1204, 'user1', 1 ),
       ( 1204, 'user6', 1 );
INSERT INTO UserAccounts ( UserID,
                           [Password],
                           [Group] )
VALUES ( 'user1', 'password', 'group1' ),
       ( 'user2', 'password', 'group10' ),
       ( 'user3', 'password', 'group1' ),
       ( 'user4', 'password', 'group4' ),
       ( 'user5', 'password', 'group10' ),
       ( 'user6', 'password', 'group10' ),
       ( 'user7', 'password', 'group2' ),
       ( 'user8', 'password', 'group10' );
```

The results were then examined using the following statement...

```
SELECT * FROM UserAccess
ORDER BY UserID,
         ID;
```

The output was as desired.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: One small thing I forgot to include was the `Active` flag column...  :/  I can't seem to alter the query to make it work.  Please see my updated question.  Thanks!!

Comment: OMG...  I just needed to change it to a `1` in my query!  Thanks!  Checking it out right now...

Comment: I have to go and attend a family Easter lunch.  I will be back in a few hours and will be able to reply to any questions or comments then.